# Perl Regular Expression to extract value from nested html tags

Tags: html, regex, perl

```
$match = q(<a href="#google"><h1><b>Google</b></h1></a>);
if($match =~ /<a.*?href.*?><.?>(.*?)<\/a>/){
$title = $1;
}else {
$title="";
}
print"$title";
```

OUTPUT: `Google</b></h1>`

It Should be : `Google`

Unable to extract value from link using Regex in Perl, it could have one more or less nesting:

```
<h1><b><i>Google</i></b></h1>
```

Please Try this:

1) <td><a href="/wiki/Unix_shell" title="Unix shell">Unix shell</a>

2) <a href="http://www.hp.com"><h1><b>HP</b></h1></a>

3) <a href="/wiki/Generic_programming" title="Generic programming">generic</a></td>);

4) <a href="#cite_note-1"><span>[</span>1<span>]</span></a>

OUTPUT:

Unix shell

HP

generic

[1]

Comment: Don't use Regex to parse HTML. It's a Bad Idea™.

Comment: Your expression says "take everything until the closing `</a>`", and that's what you get. You need to use `<\/b>`

Comment: Perl has many fine HTML parsers (such as [this one](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)). Don't use regex.

Comment: I know though for extracting value , almost working , failing while excluding closing tags, Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($match =~ /<a.*?href.*?><b>(.*?)<\/b>/)
```

That should take "everything after the `href` and between the `<b>...</b>` tags

Instead, to get "everything after the last `>` and before the first `</`, you can use

```
<a.*?href.*?>([^>]*?)<\/
```

Comment: Floris , it could have one more or less nesting: <a href="#google"><h1><b><i>Google</i></b></h1></a>

Comment: @user1239790 - I have given a second expression to handle "any nesting".

Comment: Tried following: does not work:
  if($match =~ /<a.*?href.*?>([^>]*?)<\/a>/){
  $title = $1;
  }else {
  $title="";
  }

Comment: The expression you used is not the expression I gave. What result do you get when you use my second expression? I tested it on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html and it was fine.

Comment: Working... Just need to remove html tags if any under <a>***</a> and get the value.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use regexes, as mentioned in the comments. I am especially fond of the [Mojo suite](http://mojolicio.us/), which allows me to use CSS selectors:

```
use Mojo;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(q(<a href="#google"><h1><b>Google</b></h1></a>));

print $dom->at('a[href="#google"]')->all_text, "\n";
```

Or with [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath):

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $dom = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content(q(<a href="#google"><h1><b>Google</b></h1></a>));

print $dom->findvalue('//a[@href="#google"]'), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>For this simple case you could use:</strike> The requirements are no longer simple, look at @amon's answer for how to use an HTML parser.

---

```
/<a.*?>([^<]+)</
```

Match an opening `a` tag, followed by anything until you find something between `>` and `<`.

Though as others have mentioned, you should generally use a HTML parser.

```
echo '<td><a href="/wiki/Unix_shell" title="Unix shell">Unix shell</a>
<a href="http://www.hp.com"><h1><b>HP</b></h1></a>
<a href="/wiki/Generic_programming" title="Generic programming">generic</a></td>);' | perl -ne '/<a.*?>([^<]+)</; print "$1\n"'
Unix shell
HP
generic
```

Comment: @user1239790 are you starting to see why you shouldn't use regex?

Comment: Shouldn't your expression be `/<a.*?>([^>]+)</` rather than `/<a.*?>([^<]+)</` - i.e. "no more close brackets, and then an "open end-of tag".?

Comment: Yes, i saw, regex issues with tags, Can't we have regex solution for above?

Comment: This will grab your text between your nested tags. `/(?<=^|>)([^><]+?)(?=<|$)/`

Comment: @hwnd yes it does - but it (the expression given in the answer, not the one in your comment) would fail with multiple nested tags.

Comment: @hwnd: thanks man .. i am getting some error with regex- Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<=^|>)([^><]+?)(?=<|$)/

Comment: @RobEarl: Cool it is working ;)
Is it possible to get [1] from 
Link: <a href="#cite_note-1"><span>[</span>1<span>]</span></a>

Comment: Not using this, @amon 's answer will do that though.

Comment: @RobEarl - Just need to remove html tags if any under <a>***</a> and get the value.

Comment: @RobEarl - It is final link that needs to be parsed :( .

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this regex that works for all your sampled inputs under PCRE. This regex is equivalent to a regular grammar with the tail-recursive pattern (?1)*

(?<=>)((?:\w+)(?:\s*))(?1)*

Just take the first element of the returned array, ie array[0]